# HOOK-ERROR in after_step: AttributeError: '_RunnerWrapper' object has no attribute 'log_capture'

Tags: pycharm, python-behave

I'm getting this error when I try to run a feature inside PyCharm. 
If I disable log capturing with --no-logcapture, I don't receive this error anymore.

I know there's an error in my test, but my question is: is it possible to show logging inside of PyCharm?

My PyCharm version is 2017.1 and behave version is 1.2.6

Comment: Better post to https://github.com/behave/behave/issues